# Is there a way to get the type of an uninitialised variable in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a variable `a` declared with type `string`, but uninitialised. Is there a way to get the `string` type instead of an `undefined`?

```js
> let a:string;
undefined
> console.log(typeof a);
undefined
```

Comment: No. There is no way. At runtime, the type of `a` is `undefined`. The `string` type is just a compile-time construct.

Comment: well, ok. is there any trick for this? if the variable `a` is a property in a class, would there be a way to set the type somehow in the constructor?

Comment: No. Javascript *variables* don't have a type, only *values* assigned to them have. If the assigned value is `undefined`, then `typeof` is `'undefined'`. You'd have to save this as another variable, e.g. `const a_type = 'string'`.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: You can use Default parameter value in the constructor like `constructor(a = '')`. So, if no value is passed but still it'll be of type string. `class Test { constructor(a = '') { this.a = a; } }
console.log(typeof new Test().a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is a way to get types metadata in typescript, but you would have to activate reflect metadata option in typescript compiler config and import reflect metadata polyfill, which will increase you bundle size.

look [here](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4) to find more suitable example of accessing typescript types.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no way to get the type at runtime; and based on @deceze's comment (save the metadata separately)

In case it helps someone this *workaround* does the job. It does not use Reflect `decorators`

```js
> class C {
  constructor(
     public var1?:string, 
     public var2?:string, 
     public var3?:number
  ) {}
  typeof(v) {
     switch (v) {
     case 'var1':
     case 'var2':
       return 'string';
     case 'var3':
       return 'number';
     }
   }
}
> let c = new C();
> console.log(Object.keys(c).map( 
     a => {
       console.log( ' Var: ' + a + 
                    ' - Type: ' + c.typeof(`${a}`) )
     })
  );

 Var: var1 - Type: string
 Var: var2 - Type: string
 Var: var3 - Type: number
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQqqoAOBARiAJbDQBuYeAjAPwBcueRpgDmAGmiUqtBszYcATHwFCxEqjXpMW7PAGY+mAgFs6AUzyUAlIgC+lHAE9qp9ADMyrXmEwPryddAQAO6MOMAAFtAefpKowJCm0ADkOpxJvLFoCck68umZqHimOAR4mMnKIkkA3JnxEIkpHLr5AYXFpeVJhibmNZl2VHZ2SCDFaNAAvNCYpkFwZJa1SBjY6GMAdCDowmQA8nQAVqbEGwDWpg4QZMCWG0Zg1GRq6mBTAHyIBWhYEOumWx2zyS0AAahxeMloABqaBvWHfNpIkEAWmgABUnKZISDYcANo5nG4yAADAAkCDANhJ1ksAzpqCWQA)